# How to put sql result into single cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I'm coding sql in a simplified platform and can't access the platform code so I need some workaround every now and then (not always the best practise code).

I would need to store result of select clause to single cell for further use.

For example:
Table products has `productID, productName, packages`.

Table variants has `productID, packageID`.

Example data of variants:

```
productID - packageID
1001 - K1001
1001 - K1002
1001 - K1003
```

I would need to save the result to cell packages in form of (`K1001, K1002, K1003`) or similar.

Is this possible to do just using sql?

I'm using ms sql server xpress, platform/RDBMS is custom coded and not widely known.

Comment: Which database are you using?  E.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: Yes, and what is your RDBMS? Plz add that tag.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDBMS

Comment: You want to store multiple values in one field? That is a multi-value field and only Access db platform has multi-value field structure. Believe me, you do NOT want to store multiple values in one field in SQLServer db. The result would be nothing but a string of text, not discrete units of data and will give you all kinds of pain.

Comment: String of text is exactly what I need since it only for view & print - data is always edited through original source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STUFF` with `FOR XML PATH`.

**Query**

```
select productID, stuff((
    select ', ' + packageID
    from your_table_name 
    where (productID = t.productID) 
    for xml path(''), type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '') as single_value
from your_table_name  t
group by productID;
```

**[Find demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/651245/how-to-put-sql-result-into-single-cell)**

Comment: Wow you guys are fast. I will try this. Thanks!

Comment: How would I go about selecting single instance say where productID=1001 ?

Comment: @rami : Use a `where` clause before the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Starting on SQL Server vNext you can do:

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(productId + ' - ' + packageId, ',')
FROM yourTable
```

In previous versions you are going to either hack your way through with cursors/xml or use a CLR aggregation function.